# Angular ui binding issue

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to bind a late calculated field to my ui with not much of success, This is my controller -

```
PaymentsController = ['$scope', 'Payment','Campaign', ($scope, Payment,Campaign)->
Payment.query().then((payments) ->
$scope.payments = payments
angular.forEach($scope.payments,(payment,index)->
  payment.from = $scope.getFrom(payment)
)
```

The concept is simple, but the method getFrom returns a promise, when i get to this controller i load a list, the ui looks like this:

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-bind="'from'|i18n"></th>
                    <th ng-bind="'amount'|i18n"></th>
                    <th ng-bind="'to'|i18n"></th>
                    <th ng-bind="'description'|i18n"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="payment in payments">
                    <td ng-bind="payment.from"></td>
                    <td>{{getAmount(payment)}}</td>
                    <td>{{getTo(payment)}}</td>
                    <td>{{getDescription(payment)}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-show="!payments.length">
                    <td ng-bind="'no_payments'|i18n"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

nothing fency,
all fields are bind as expected except the from, according to controller i expect to see "asd"
but i see nothing.

I need to return a promise in this method but first I'm trying to make it work with simple code.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was more conceptual I guess, I managed to fix this by making the controller control the view and not the view to control the controller, so instead of assigning a promise to the "from" field, I declared it when I had a value to put in, so my code looks like this:

```
  angular.forEach($scope.payments, (payment, index)->
    $scope.resolveFrom(payment)
  )

$scope.resolveFrom = (payment)->
  if payment.amount < 0
    payment.from = "1"
  else if payment.campaign_id
    Campaign.get(payment.campaign_id)
    .then((campaign)->
            payment.from = campaign.name)))

  payment.from = "unkown"
```

I'm not sure if this is the best practice, would appreciate comments/alternative solutions.